# Adding tags for five points of Calvinism(TULIP) and for terminology associated with Arminianism doctrine

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, interesting-tags

It's really good that we have a tag called predestination which would take into account the Calvinism doctrine, and furthermore, the term predestination is more descriptive and indicative of what the doctrine is actually about which is Predestination, and therefore, we do Not want the tag Calvinism there.

However, could you please also add tags for the following five points of Calvinism(TULIP):

1. Total Depravity(total inability)
2. Unconditional Election
3. Limited Atonement ("particular redemption" or "definite atonement")
4. Irresistible Grace ( "efficacious grace" )
5. Perseverance of the Saints ("perseverance of God with the saints" and "preservation of the believing")

I still need to read up more on the terminology associated with Arminianism doctrine, but could you please also add tags for terminology associated with Arminianism doctrine?

Comment: Calvin deserves a better consideration and a better memorial than such a superficial acronym that trivialises his work (and trivialises Paul's doctrine also).

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd be cautious against creating too many theological tags, as this is a Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, rather than Theology, and though the two are intertwined, the focus of this site should always be the text itself and the authorial intent. This may cause confusion for new users coming onto the site as they grow to understand the scope and focus of the site.

I would suggest that '**Predestination**' is a good term for many of these types of questions, as it is a historic term which goes back reliably to the texts themselves, whereas the points of Calvinism only date back a few centuries. Questions around theological viewpoints belong on the Christianity Stack Exchange, and users are welcome to ask questions there from particular theological viewpoints.

Another tag you may find helpful is '**soteriology**', which is the field of study around biblical ideas of salvation, and that would cover many of these points you're interested in.